# Extract values between two rows with specific text (dynamic range)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am wondering is there an Excel formula solution for this? I know it can be done with VBA but just for sake of simplicity I would prefer doing it with Excel formula if it is possible.

There are two guidelines `Start range` and `End range` (typo in example). I would like to get text in rows in between, in this case `Part one` and `Part two`. The problem is that there are can be more lines, like `Part three` and `Part four` = Range is dynamic.

Basically (like VBA) formula should find two words in Column C `Start range` and `End range` and get text in between, starting from first one after `Start range` and until last one before `End range`.

Is there any way to perform this with Excel formula?

I can probably get cell position by using SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((C2:C5="Start range")*ROW(C2:C5))
```

and

```
=SUMPRODUCT((C2:C5="Eng range")*ROW(C2:C5))
```

[image]

---

EDIT:

This seems to work, but it is giving only first result in range as an output. How to get all results within the range by using "drag down"?

```
=INDEX($C:$C;N(IF(1;ROW(INDEX($C:$C;MATCH("Start range";$C:$C;0)+1,1):INDEX($C:$C;MATCH("Eng range";$C:$C;0)-1;1)))))
```

Result should be:

```
Part one
Part two
```

Comment: Do you have access to the FILTER function? and SEQUENCE?

Comment: @BigBen unfortunately not.

Comment: What would your end result look like? You mentioned you want to *get text* in betweeen?

Comment: @JvdV I have edited my question. See edit section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
=INDEX(C:C,SMALL(IF((ROW(C:C)>MATCH("Start Range",C:C,0))*(ROW(C:C)<MATCH("Eng Range",C:C,0))=1,ROW(C:C),""),ROW(A1)))
```

Or to make your formula work:

```
=INDEX(INDEX($C:$C;N(IF(1;ROW(INDEX($C:$C;MATCH("Start range";$C:$C;0)+1,1):INDEX($C:$C;MATCH("Eng range";$C:$C;0)-1;1))))),ROW(A1))
```

Enter as array through CSE, and drag the formula down.